# Disable scroll of ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need disable scroll of ion-content because im using ion-scroll on a custom component. Already tried set no-bounce and ion-fixed on ion-content. I also tried set this css:

```
.content .scroll-content {
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

but it doesnt works.
I just need disable the scroll of content and preserve the scroll of custom component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it doesn't work"? Didn't it work too much on the contrary, and disabled all your app scrolls? if so, you should attribute this style to `.no-scroll .scroll-content` rather, and add `class="no-scroll"` to the element you want to disable the scroll

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by two different approaches :

In SCSS:-

```
ion-content {--overflow: hidden}
```

OR

In Html:-

```
<ion-content scroll-y="false">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ion-content {
     --overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .scss file

```
.no-scroll .scroll-content{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then add the no-scroll class to your ion-content like this

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
..
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi Junior!
I tried this solution, but it hide the scroll of my custom components inside the content...

Answer (score 0):

Setting `scrollY` to `false` worked for me:

```
<IonContent scrollY={false}>
...
</IonContent>
```